# Upgrade to: Grails 3.3.2, setting server URL

Tags: grails, upgrade, grails-3.3

Hi I m upgrading existing Grails 2.4.5 to Grails 3.3.2. I followed https://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html. Grails app runs at localhost:8080, but I want server URL as http://localhost:8080/projectName. I tried adding the following to application.yml:

```
environments:
   development:
     grails:
       serverURL: http://localhost:8080/projectName
```

And URLMappings.groovy looks like below:

```
"/"(view:"/index")
"500"(view:'/error')
"404"(view:'/notFound')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **server.contextPath**:

```
environments:
  development:
    server:
      contextPath: /projectName
```

Comment: in Grails 3.3.2, can I use like: render company as JSON inside a controller?

Comment: Yes,  do you have any problems with it?

Comment: Yes, example, in render company as JSON (JSON in red color and Cannot resolve JSON) . Should I use something like http://docs.grails.org/snapshot/ref/Controllers/render.html?

Comment: import grails.converters.JSON

Comment: You need to add dependency to build.gradle: compile "org.grails.plugins:converters"

Comment: Its present in build.gradle, my code in CompanyController is,   def company = Company.findAll() JSON.use ('deep') render company as JSON.

Comment: Create sample project and give us a link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924683/grails-3-3-2-controllers-json-not-resolved